How did Galois classify Abelian integrals without using Riemann surfaces?
In modern presentations, the classification of Abelian integrals into three kinds uses properties of Riemann surfaces. To what extent did Galois anticipate the concept of Riemann surfaces? And if he did not then what mathematical methods did he use to classify the integrals?

Galois' ideas on what came to be called Abelian integrals are known only in a sketch from a letter to Chevallier written on the evening before his death in a duel, May 29, 1832. The original text and English translation are available on nLab.
Galois' classification is analytic and does not involve geometric language used by Riemann in 1857. However, his formulations parallel Riemann's in terms of poles and branch points. Galois generalizes analytic classification of elliptic integrals introduced by Legendre in 1793 based on the type of functions that come up in the so-called addition theorems, see Kleiman, What is Abel’s Theorem Anyway? The addition theorems go back to Euler for some elliptic integrals, and were proved for Abelian integrals by Abel in a paper published posthumously in 1841. They were, apparently, anticipated by Galois, who writes the following:

"We know that a sum of terms of the same elliptic function is always reduced to a
single term plus algebraic or logarithmic quantities. There are no other functions for which this property holds. But very similar properties hold if we substitute everywhere, integrals of algebraic functions. We treat at the same time all the integrals for which the differential is a function of the variable and of a similar irrational function of the variable, whether this irrational is or is not a radical, whether it may be expressible or not expressible by radicals. We find that the number of distinct periods of the most general integral related to a given irrational is always an even number. Letting $2n$ be this number we have the following theorem: An arbitrary sum of terms reduces to $n$ terms, plus algebraic and logarithmic
quantities.  The functions of the first kind are those for which the algebraic and logarithmic part is zero. There are $n$ distinct ones. The functions of the second kind are those for which the complementary part is
purely algebraic. There are $n$ distinct ones. We can suppose that the differentials of other functions are never infinity but once for $x = a$, and moreover, that their complementary part is reduced to only one logarithm, $\log P$, $P$ being an algebraic quantity... the periods of functions of the third kind are always expressible as a function of first and second kind. We can also deduce theorems analogous to the theorems of Legendre... The reduction of functions of the third kind to definite integrals, which is the
most beautiful discovery of Jacobi, is not practicable outside the case of elliptic
functions."

The mathematics of Galois' letter is analyzed by Picard in the preface to Galois' Collected Works. For English translation see Papadopoulos, Looking backward: From Euler to Riemann:

"We thus acquire the certainty that he possessed the most
essential results on Abelian integrals that Riemann was led to obtain twenty-five years later. We see without surprise Galois talking about the periods of an Abelian integral relative to an arbitrary algebraic function [...] The statements are precise; the famous author makes the classification of Abelian integrals into three kinds,
and he declares that if n denotes the number of linearly independent integrals of the first kind, the number of periods is $2n$. The theorem relative to the parameter inversion in the integrals of the third type is clearly marked, as well as the relations with the periods of Abelian integrals. Galois also talks about a generalization
of Legendre’s classical equation where the periods of elliptic integrals appear, a generalization which probably led him to the important relation that was discovered later on by Weierstrass and Mr. Fuchs."

Kleiman adds that one more of Galois' assertions, that (in modern terminology) the division by $n$ of the sum of $p$ Abelian integrals of genus $p$ leads to an equation of degree $n^{2p}$, was proved by Clebsch in 1864.
